# How to stop nested list from inheriting style from parent list?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a nested list but I am having a problem with it inheriting from the parent list. I've followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897463/css-on-nested-list-avoid-styling-of-both-lists) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247525/my-nested-li-is-inheriting-the-styles-from-its-parent) but they haven't helped.

How could I get rid of the red background in the nested list?

http://jsfiddle.net/wHztz/25/

```
<div class="innerLeft">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Fruit</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Apples</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Vegetable</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

.innerLeft ul {
    width:199px;
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 0 0 12px;
    list-style:none;
    min-height:10px;
}
.innerLeft ul li {
    background: red;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px 0 10px 0;
    height:18px;
}
.innerLeft ul li ul {
    background: '';
}
.innerLeft ul li ul li {
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use background-color in `li` use it in anchor

```
.innerLeft ul li a{
    background: red;
    display:block;
}
```

this will solve your issue

**[updated jsFiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/wHztz/32/)**

Comment: thanks! I just realized the problem with this, how do you stop the nested list going over the next <li> in the parent list? See the red background isn't moving down correctly? This is a problem because the colors are actually placeholders for images. http://jsfiddle.net/wHztz/65/

Comment: nevermind, got the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886161/how-to-stop-nested-list-overlapping-parent-list :)

Answer (score 1):

The following rule tells the browser to render any list element inside `innerLeft` with a red background:

```
.innerLeft ul li {
    background: red;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px 0 10px 0;
    height:18px;
}
```

Use specificity to target the first ul:

```
ul li {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.innerLeft > ul li {
    background: red;
    ...
}
```

By using the `>` selector, you are telling the browser to select the child of `.innerLeft`, or direct descendant.