# How to stop nested list overlapping parent list?

Tags: html, css

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/wHztz/67/

In this example the colors are placeholders for background images, I noticed the nested list stops overlapping when the `display:block` is removed from `.innerLeft ul li a` but then the background images wont show correctly.

I don't have much experience with CSS. Is there a way around this? Thanks!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="innerLeft">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Fruit</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Apples</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Apples</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Apples</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Apples</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Apples</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Apples</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Apples</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Apples</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Vegetable</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.innerLeft ul {
    width:199px;
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 0 0 12px;
    list-style:none;
    min-height:10px;
}
.innerLeft ul li{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px 0 10px 0;
    height:18px;
}
.innerLeft ul li a{
    background: red;
    display:block;
}
.innerLeft ul li ul li a{
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.innerLeft ul li {
    clear: left; /* Added */
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px 0 10px 0;
    height:18px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wHztz/70/

Answer (score 0):

use `display:inline-block;` instead

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wHztz/71/)

```
.innerLeft ul li a{
    background: red;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Its happening because you have applied css to `ul li a` and not `ul li ul` :)